# How to know if the user has downloaded the Android app from US playstore or Canada playstore programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am working on an Android app which needs to be deployed only in US and Canada playstores. The flow and certain features in the app changes as per the country in which it is downloaded.
So, I have to detect whether the user has downloaded it from US or Canada playstore at the very beginning of the app.
As I wanted the detection to be more specific and accurate, I didn't choose 
 the other options like locale and finding user location using gps etc.,
Excited about the different solutions you might suggest :)
Thank you

Comment: Google Play store lets you specify where your app is launched. So you can create 2 versions, one for North America and the other for the rest of the world, just specify different countries when launching to play store.

Comment: Tuby's answer is the right way to do things. An Apk has no idea of where it was downloaded from.

Comment: Awesome. Now the roadway is clear. moving forward as suggested. Thank you

Comment: @satyaphani It has been a while but have you actually done that? It doesn't look like you can publish different flavours under same package name.